# NTP configuration is not working

Tags: wifi, ntp, settings

I'm working with 10 raspberry and they are all connected to the same network via Wifi.
I need to get the right time from the network, so I modified the ntp.conf file with the IP of my network (10.1.65.10 and 10.1.65.11) that I wanna use to retrive the right time.

I've rebooted the raspberries but now three of them they still have a wrong time, I've also checked the time location but the location is right.

Can someone helps me? Which is the best way to modify the ntp.conf file? Should I modify other files?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to be sure: So there are NTP servers on your network at those addresses?

Comment: Yes, there are..there is a command to get the data directly from the NTP server? just to be sure that is working properly?

Comment: Dunno, I've never run one.  I despise `ntp`, TBH -- it's one of those things where when it works, it works and that is terrific, when it doesn't, it begins to strike me as atrociously designed, particularly in the "user interface" department.  You might want to ask about this on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead ("instead" because they don't like cross-posting, so if you do that delete this one first or leave a comment @goldilocks and I can close it).

Comment: I know, that is the reason why I opened this topic...But I wanna try to solve my problem because NTP is the only way that I should use to do that.

Comment: Well, I think your RPis should have lines in ntp.conf `server 10.1.65.10 iburst`  `server 10.1.65.11 iburst` or, given that you have many RPis possibly you could use one of those to broadcast to the RPis.  Don't forget that for each `server` line each RPi will send/receive a packet to/from them each time it polls them (initially one every 64 seconds IIRC) - are your RPiS using off-site `servers` (e.g. of form <#>.<geo-graphic ID>.pool.ntp.org) - I wonder if there are issues with all those "time" packets? Also, if you do not use the "iburst" option it takes `ntp` daemons a while to sync-up,,,!